# Addthis breaks magiczoomplus on chrome on pc

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis, magiczoomplus

Adding **addThis** on my site breaks **Magiczoomplus** on chrome on PC only.

When zooming in the image randomly shifts size.

I have tried using jQuery.noConflict() without success but I am not a jQuery expert, I might have done it wrong.

Any ideas ?

Here is the html code :

```js
$('.magnifier').click(function() {
        return MagicZoom.expand('jeans');
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://www.magictoolbox.com/static/magiczoomplus/magiczoomplus.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.magictoolbox.com/static/magiczoomplus/magiczoomplus.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product_zoom" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" class="modal fade cboxElement">

              <button data-dismiss="modal" title="Close" class="mz-button mz-button-close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3">
                <h2>Jacket</h2>
                <p><i>244662</i>black</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sx-12 col-md-7 col-lg-5"><a id="jeans" data-options="zoomMode: off; variableZoom: true; zoomPosition: inner;  upscale: true; cssClass: white-bg fl-zoom; expand: window" href="https://dnsv4oxp52xck.cloudfront.net/244/2446620001_png_zoom_1.jpg" class="MagicZoom"><img src="https://dnsv4oxp52xck.cloudfront.net/244/2446620001_png_zoom_1.jpg" style="max-width: 2000px; max-height: 2000px;" class="main-visual"></a>
                <div class="thumbs-container"><a data-image="https://dnsv4oxp52xck.cloudfront.net/244/2446620001_png_zoom_1.jpg" href="https://dnsv4oxp52xck.cloudfront.net/244/2446620001_png_zoom_1.jpg" data-zoom-id="jeans" class="mz-thumb"><img src="https://dnsv4oxp52xck.cloudfront.net/244/2446620001_png_zoom_1.jpg" class="main-visual"></a></div>
              </div>
            </div>


      <script src="js/vendor/magiczoomplus.js" async></script>
      <script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-50ed24e34032223b" async></script>
```

Comment: Maybe, you can show some code.